# Store XML tag to Perl variable in shell

Tags: xml, perl, shell, awk

I am running the `awk` command in order to extract an XML tag from a file and it runs successfully in my console and it prints the tag needed to output

```
awk '/<tag name="some_name">/,/<\/tag>/' file
```

Now i need to call this command inside a Perl script and pass the output that was in my console to this variable in order to manipulate this structure with Perl.

I tried

```
my $var=`awk '/<tag name="some_name">/,/<\/tag>/' file`
```

But this does not work and i have this error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: /<tag name="some_name">/,/</tag>/
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                 ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

How can i modify this variable assignment or even use some other way to resolve my issue.
I am open to all propositions even not using `awk` in the first place and use only Perl.

Comment: Umm why bother calling the awk command from within Perl when it can do it just as well itself? In fact there's even `a2p` (Awk to Perl)

Comment: @vogomatix i knew that awk does this simply in just one command so i choosed awk, if it is possible with this command in perl, it would be even better, how can i use `a2p` for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting is a little tricky.  I used the `q` operator (see `perldoc perlop`) for the command itself, and [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html) instead off the equivalent backticks for clarity.

```
my $cmd = q(awk '/<tag name="some_name">/,/<\/tag>/' file);
my $var = qx($cmd);
```

I recommend using an XML parser instead, such as [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig).

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise using an actual xml parser instead, such as [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    location => 'file'
);

my @nodes = $dom->findnodes(q{//tag[@name="some_name"]});

print $nodes[0]->textContent();
```

Comment: Much more robust solution than other answers, including my own :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll edit this later as I'm not on a system running Perl but something like this will avoid using awk...

```
open FILE, "file" or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
$slurp = <FILE>;
if ($slurp =~ /<tag name="some_name">(.*)<\/tag>/) {
    $var = $1;
}
```